# add item to an array of json objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add a value to specific field of my array which is a json object.
in other words i want to append to a json object which is a field of another array.

```
var cdata = new Array();
 for (i in json2) {
     for (j in json2[i]) {
         //here i get error:
         cdata[j].push({
             'x': json2[i].timestamp,
             'y': json2[i][j]
         });
     };
 };
```

but i get Uncaught `TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined  error.`

thanks in advance

Comment: Where is json2 defined? Looks like some code is missing here.

Comment: And *sigh* there's no [JSON](http://json.org) anywhere in this question. Those are just JavaScript objects.

Comment: I've removed the JSON tag since your question doesn't seem to be related to the JSON data format at all.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling push on an array element referred to by the index j as follows cdata[j]

You should call

```
cdata.push({
         'x': json2[i].timestamp,
         'y': json2[i][j]
     });
```

Additionally - thanks to commenter - looking at the way you are iterating through the array json2 it doesn't seem right. We could do with seeing json2 to fully answer this one.

The line:

```
json2[i].timestamp
```

Suggests json2 is an array of objects

However the line:

```
json2[i][j]
```

suggests json2 is a multi-dimensional array.

See this post: [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

HTH

Comment: This is part of it, but the whole series of code seems suspect.

Comment: I know the code is insufficient but just forget about those json2. i just want to push on an array element which is a json object, how could i do that?

Comment: Provided you have an array object which is the only object that supports push natively the use push as shown.